# the correct way to calculate when the process wake up when use sleep() function

Tags: c

I'm reading a textbook which has an exercise as:

> Write a wrapper function for sleep, called `wakeup`, with the following interface:

`unsigned int wakeup(unsigned int secs);`

> The `wakeup` function behaves exactly as the sleep function, except that it prints a message describing when the process actually woke up: Woke up at 4 secs.

and the solution is:

```
unsigned int wakeup(unsigned int secs){
    int i;
    unsigned int rc = sleep(secs);
    printf("Woke up at %d secs.\n", secs-rc+1);
    return rc;
}
```

But I'm confused that why it is `secs-rc+1`, shouldn't it be `secs-rc`? let say the `secs` parameter is 3 and it resumes by receiving an signal at 1 sec, so `sleep` return 2 since it still has 2 seconds still left to sleep, then the process actually wake up at 3-2 = 1 sec? how come it is  3-2+1 = 2 sec?

Comment: I may not be very satisfying, but In a nutshell, It simply prevents ambiguity for the _normal_ return value of `0`, with the possibility of also returning `0` for a _non-normal_ return (ie. interrupt)

Answer (score 1):

*But I'm confused that why it is secs-rc+1, shouldn't it be secs-rc?*

In simplest terms, the `+1` is to prevent ambiguity of the `0` return value.

As you have correctly observed, the return for [sleep()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) states:

> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left
> to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler.

so, adding the extra `1` would be useful to prevent the function from returning a zero value in the event of an interrupt at time ==  `0`.

eg if `secs == 3`, and an interrupt occurs immediately after clock was started, then simply having `secs=rc`  would be `3 - 3 == 0`.  Same as  normal exit.

`secs-rc+1` guarantees a non-zero result for any non-normal exit to the routine.

Comment: @amjad - you have made no response.   Just curious if this answer makes sense to you?